# Firefox scrollbar resets incorrectly

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

I've come across a problem in Firefox browser. It's likely a bug, but maybe someone knows a workaround. The problem is demonstrated in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5tdB/ This has been tested on Firefox 12.0, 15.0.1, 16.0.1.

To explain it in words... You have to follow this sequence of events:

1. Get an element with `overflow:auto` and some overflowing contents, then scroll it a bit;
2. Hide the element (`display: none`);
3. Remove contents
4. Show the element (it's empty now)
5. Re-add the same contents (it's scrolled now, just as it was before)
6. Reset scrollTop/scrollLeft to 0 via Javascript.

As a result, the contents do get scrolled to the proper position, but the scrollbar stays as it was, which is clearly wrong.

Is there any workaround to this short of removing/re-adding the element instead of just hiding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In testing I discovered that if you set scrollTop to any value other than 0 (or its current value) then it updates the scrollbar correctly. You can then immediately set scrollTop to 0.

Particularly as you have a test case you should of course file a bug in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Ooh, nice! I couldn't find that on Firefox's website. I used the "Submit feedback" option from the Help menu. I'll submit a bug too.

Comment: Wow, someone's already tracked down the bug and found it started happening in April 2006! I just hope you don't have to wait another six years for the fix...

Comment: Eh, what? Where did you get that info? The forum topic that was linked later in that bug's comments? That doesn't seem to have anything remotely related. There is something about scrollbars in RTL blocks, but in my case there is nothing RTL there.

Comment: What happened was that the developer accidentally introduced your bug in an attempt to fix that apparently unrelated bug. This may help a developer to understand how to fix your bug without reintroducing the unrelated bug (which would be unhelpful).

Comment: Apparently "Alice" is good at discovering these accidental regressions once you have a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is add the animate method, so use:

```
function resetScroll(){
    $(document).scrollTop(1); // removes the impression of animation
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},'fast','linear');
}
```